# Java SQLite Update query not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After hours (basically the entire day) of wriggling around, wrapping my throughts and whatnot, I am baffled as to why my UPDATE statement in SQLite does not want to work.
It concerns the following queries:

```
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET _id = \"save\" WHERE _id = null");
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET WORLD_ONE = \""+finishedLevels+"\" WHERE _id = 'save'");
```

I've also tried

```
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET _id = 'save' WHERE _id = null");
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET WORLD_ONE = '"+finishedLevels+"' WHERE _id = 'save'");
```

but to no avail.

The function I'm calling is this:

```
public void Update(String query){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(query);

    db.close();
}
```

Debugging clearly shows that the functions is being called and stepped through but refuses to work.
Any other SQL function I call (e.g. to create new tables etc.) all have their **db.close()** call present.

I've also tried looking at a different project where the UDPATE statement does work, but I can't find any differences (instance of my SQLLib class, function calls are the same, etc.)
It would seem so simple to call an UPDATE statement, but it has a fault somewhere.

Where is this fault? Because I'm at a total loss now.

-Zubaja

Comment: What is the structure of your table?

Comment: What is the actual problem? "refuses to work" may be a little vague.

Comment: instead do it this way "_id = null" try it this way "_id is null"

Comment: @Karakuri the table is named **SAVEGAME** and has three columns, each named **WORLD** followed by a digit representing that world

Comment: @HannoBinder Sorry. What I meant to imply was: The UPDATE Queries run, but do not update values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `= null` when you need to use `is null`:

Change:

```
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET _id = \"save\" WHERE _id = null");
```

To this:

```
sql.Update("UPDATE SAVEGAME SET _id = \"save\" WHERE _id is null");
                                                        ^^^^
```

Also, you may want to check how you are creating your SQL strings - inserting variables like that leaves your code prone to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I'm on my way home from work now, so I'll update my findings in about an hour or so. Thank you for the swidt reply.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. It's one of those small things you overlook too quickly if you think the issue isn't where you think it is.
Many thanks!